# Hide Navigation Bar on rotation

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a UIView with a navigation bar. How can I hide the navigation bar when the user puts the iPhone in landscape orientation, and have it show again on portrait view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very easy to find in the documentation. In the UINavigationController docs, to hide the nav bar, you use:

```
- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated
```

If you want to do this when the device rotates, you'll want to do this in your the view controller method (mentioned in the UIViewController docs):

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Comment: if want that navigationbar should never hide when orientation is changed  , but whenever i am switch to landscape it always hides , this code is also not working. please help me

Answer (score 9):

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) animated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A better way IMHO is to use a CGAffineTransform, and leave the nav bar where it is - like the photo gallery view of the iPhone. See Jeff Lamarche's excellent introduction [Demystifying CGAffineTransform](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html). Helped me quite a bit.